# MiKTeX: 2.9.7440 Update Issue

Tags: miktex-update

I am running MiKTeX: 2.9.7440 and wished to use the Beamer package (which wasn't installed). However, when I tried to install it, I received an error message: "The following issues were detected: 1: minor issue: It has been a long time since a MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates." I have searched the web for any advice on how to fix this problem but with no success. Apologies for a probably very simple question from someone not too expert with the MikTeX Console.

Comment: the miktex console has in the file menu an entry that let you switch to the admin mode. Do that and search there for updates.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good chance the option provided by Ulrike Fischer might not work. As of April 17, 2023 the MikTeX distribution has reached version 23.4. The console belonging to that distribution is version 4.9. You can check the installed versions in TeXStudio (probably in other editors as well) using *Help > Check LaTeX installation*. All information about the installed MikTeX distribution and TeXStudio will be displayed in a new TeXStudio window.

There are a few options to proceed in updating your distribution. One is given in the comment. I will give a few alternatives below.

**Final solution**
Sounds ominous, but it is just a sure way to get the newest version and packages installed.

1. Delete your old MikTeX distribution using the Windows *Remove Apps* option.
2. Alternatively, rename your old distribution folder so you have a rollback option.
3. Download the newest distribution setup file from [MikTeX](https://miktex.org/download) and install that. It actually doesn't matter whether you're administrator or user on a system you work on alone. Administrator just installs for *all users* on that computer.
4. Open the newly installed MikTeX Console and tap on the menu item **Tasks**. Select *Refresh file name database*.
5. Next tap the same menu item and now select **Check Updates**. This can also be done in the side menu.
6. Open an existing *tex* file to download the packages you used before (by and large that would be a large portion of your packages).
7. If you want to use the *documentation* of the packages, check the **Documentation** option in the side menu. Nowadays only a few packages are installed including their documentation files.
8. As a last action tap on *Tasks* again and select the two middle options one after the other. All information about your distribution will be updated for use.

**Next best option**
If you have a version that was last updated after July 2022, you can try to use the steps **4-5-7-8** of the *Final solution*.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. The option provided by Ulrike did not work so I will follow your advice and implement steps 1 to 8.  I am using MikTeX Console 2.9.7429 and, as you predicted, steps 4-5-7-8 did not work. Step 2 (rollback option) is a really good idea.  Thanks again. John Carroll

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. I’d like to know why. What is wrong with this answer and how could it be improved? To my knowledge there is nothing wrong with it.